# How do I check if the three last characters of a variable match another variable?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch, script, environment-variables

I have `%var1%` and `%var2%`

```
var1="UserInput"
var2=file.log
```

If a user types `%var1%` as "file.txt", how can I (if possible) check only the three last characters *(Or the file format if that's possible)* to see if it matches `%var2%`'s three last characters or file format?

Another method that does the same thing is also welcome (But the user-input variable **must** be there)

Comment: Seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are going to check a fixed number of characters, then you should check the last 4, else "file.Log" will match "file.myLog".

But the best option is to get the actual extension, regardless the length:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "var1=file.Log"
set "var2=file.myLog"

:: Option 1 using FOR loops
for %%A in ("%var1%") do for %%B in ("%var2%") do if "%%~xA"=="%%~xB" (
  echo Match
) else (
  echo No Match
)

: Option 2 using CALL parameters
call :matchExtension "%var1%" "%var2%" &&echo Match||echo No Match
exit /b

:matchExtension file1 fil2 --> returns 0 (success) if match, 1 (error) if no match
if "%~x1"=="%~x2" exit /b 0
exit /b 1
```

Answer (score 5):

#### How do I check if the three last characters of a variable match another variable?

Use variable substring syntax to extract the last 3 characters of each variable.

Example batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set /p var1="UserInput: "
set var1last3=%var1:~-3%
set var2=file.log
set var2last3=%var2:~-3%
if %var1last3% == %var2last3% (
  echo Match
  ) else (
  echo No Match
  )
endlocal
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [If - Conditionally perform command - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)
- [Set - Environment Variable - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)
- [variable substring - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)

Comment: It doesn't affect your answer's functionality, but why have you set `enabledelayedexpansion` when you don't use any `!var!` expansions?

Comment: @AFH Force of habit. I've removed it to avoid any confusion:)

Comment: While your code answers the question, it doesn't really solve the problem. Examples where it won't work correctly: `list.txt` vs `listxt`, `stuff.docx` vs `stuff.ocx`, `file1.o` vs `file2.o`. These are all valid extensions for actual file formats, only `listxt` is a made up extension-less file name.